# Am I incorrectly using the unnamed semaphore variable?

Tags: synchronization, shared-memory

I'm trying to write a program in which main process allocate a shared memory and then forks 4 times. Each process then increment by 1, a integer variable in the shared memory 500 times. So the integer variable finally holds 2500. Before accessing the shared memory, a process locks a semaphore and after writing the shared memory, the process unlocks it. But program gives me the following result.

```
tracking@ubuntu12.04:~/thread$ ./a.out
shared memory value : 500 by 28488 process
shared memory value : 1000 by 28487 process
shared memory value : 2179 by 28490 process
shared memory value : 1500 by 28489 process
shared memory value : 2500 by 28491 process
tracking@ubuntu12.04:~/thread$ ./a.out
shared memory value : 500 by 28493 process
shared memory value : 1000 by 28492 process
shared memory value : 2500 by 28495 process
shared memory value : 1500 by 28494 process
shared memory value : 2000 by 28496 process
tracking@ubuntu12.04:~/thread$ ./a.out
shared memory value : 500 by 28498 process
shared memory value : 1000 by 28497 process
shared memory value : 1500 by 28501 process
shared memory value : 2000 by 28499 process
shared memory value : 2500 by 28500 process
```

the first result shows strange value, 2179. I also think intermediate result should be in-order, Because only one process can access the shared memory at a time. But The second result shows 500, 1000, 2500, 1500, 2000. it's out-of-order result.

Here is code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>

#define KEY_NUM 9527
#define MEM_SIZE 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char        buffer[1024];
    char        *c;
    int         i, n, status;
    pid_t       childpid = 0;
    sem_t       my_lock;
    int         counter = 0;
    int         shm_id;
    void        *shm_addr;

    if( (shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, MEM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1)
    {
        printf("fail to allocate a shared memory.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    shm_addr = shmat(shm_id, (void*)0, 0);

    *(int*)shm_addr = 0; // initially 0.

    if( sem_init(&my_lock, 1, 1) == -1)
    {
        perror("Could not initialize mylock semaphore");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i = 0;  i < 4; i++)
        if(0 == fork()) 
            break;      // child process exit for-loop.

    // entry section
    if( sem_wait(&my_lock) == -1)
    {
        perror("Semaphore invalid");
        exit(1);
    }
    // start of critical section.

    for(i = 0 ; i < 500; i++)
    {
        *(int*)shm_addr = *(int*)shm_addr + 1;
    }
    sprintf(buffer, "shared memory value : %d by %ld process\n", *(int*)shm_addr, (long)getpid());
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, strlen(buffer) );
    // end of critical section.

    // exit section
    if (sem_post(&my_lock) == -1)
    {
        perror("Semaphore done");
        exit(1);
    }

    // remainder section
    if(childpid > 0)
    {
        for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) // wait for all children.
            wait(&status);
        shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, 0); // deallocate the shared memory.
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

I don't find what goes wrong. What should I do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semaphore you created is not in the shared memory, so after `fork` each process has separate copy of the it. You need to keep both counter and semaphore in shared memory, use a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have used unnamed semaphore in your code.

unnamed semaphore can work for two things

1. between threads of one process.
2. between related processes.

you have used related processes in your code.

the problem in your code is , you do not share your semaphore variable.

i.e. let there is one process named `A` it has `count` variable then you use `fork()` . so now there are two processes , parent process is A , and child process is let B , remember after `fork()` both the processes A and B have their own copy of count variable. so if process A change the count variable then the change do not reflects in the process B.

so if you want that the change made by process A also reflects in process B then you have the share count variable.